# Change list with LINQ depending on variable

Tags: c#

I have a variable selectedValue. This can have the value steel or iron.  And I have a list listB with three int values.
Two cases:

1. If selectedValue has the value steel then the list listB should also have the three int values 1, 21 and 45.
2. If selectedValue has the value iron then the list listB should only have the two int values 1 and 45.

This is a simple example.
My question: How can I remove the value 21 from the list listB if selectedValue has the value iron with LINQ. It should be solved with LINQ.
Is there a solution with LINQ?

```
string selectedValue = "steel";    // or selectedValue can have the value "iron" 

var listB = new List<int>();
listB.Add(1);
listB.Add(21);
listB.Add(45);
```

Comment: `int[] values = s == "iron" ? [1, 45] : [1, 21, 45];` ?

Comment: `var listB = selectedValue == "steel" ? new List<int>() {1, 21, 45} : new List<int>() {1, 45};`

Answer (score 0):

Linq is designed for querying, not updating, so it can't cleanly be used to "remove" an item. You can create a *new* list without that item, but you can't update the list.

Honestly, if it were me, I'd just keep it simple:

```
string selectedValue = "steel";    // or selectedValue can have the value "iron" 

var listB = new List<int>();
listB.Add(1);
listB.Add(45);
if (selectedValue=="steel")
{
    listB.Add(21);
}
```

If you have multiple cases that don't overlap as much, you could create multiple lists in a dictionary, using the metal name as keys, and select the list based on the key value.

You end up making things *more* complicated when you try to use Linq where it's not designed to be used.

Answer (score -2):

`listB.RemoveAll(t=> selectedValue=="iron" && t == 21)`

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to remove data in the original source with LINQ. LINQ expressions will use the source, which is an `IEnumerable<T>`, and read or transform the data, see [Language Integrated Query (LINQ) - Query expression overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/#query-expression-overview):

> ### Query expression overview
>
> - Query expressions can be used to query and to transform data from any LINQ-enabled data source. [...]

Neither the [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-8.0) interface nor the [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=net-8.0) interface have methods to remove data from the source, only to "read" data from the source.

Comment: Pedantically, yes. I don't think OP intended that,.

Answer (score -2):

Well you have two options:

```
listB.RemoveAll(val => selectedValue == "iron" && val == 21);

listB = listB.Where(val => val != 21 || selectedValue != "iron").ToList();
```

The first Option was already suggested but for some reason downvoted.
So I guess the second answere would be more "LINQ"y although it really isnt pretty.

If you however wanted Answeres written in the query format this would be it for Option 2

```
 listB = (from val in listB
     where val != 21 || selectedValue != "iron"
     select val).ToList();
```

I can not translate Option 1 into this format. So this is the best I can do for you